# How to download file served by aspx address

Tags: asp.net, node.js, http

If I paste the following link in a browser a dialog pops up and asks to if I want to download a zip file:

`www.foo.com/download.aspx?q=fjg82nnjlslsdfjsdf`

If I try to download with a request programmatically I get an Error Connection Reset:

`request({url:fileUrl, encoding: null},function(err, resp, body){
    if(err) throw err; //always an error connection reset error
})`

No problems with links that end with static files ex. www.foo.com/car.bmp, www.foo.com/car.png, www.foo.com/car.jpg, etc, but since the file is sitting "behind" the asp page I can't download it.

Comment: It's unlikely that's the real problem.  Can you download any other file from that site?  My guess is that your code can't connect at all to the webserver or you have an SSL or proxy problem.

Comment: @David there are no other endpoints for me to test on the site, but I can download static files fine from other sites no problem.  Let me go research  SSL problems

Comment: @David you're right it was a SSL problem, I needed to bump up to ````SSLv3_method````